# Ada: Convert float to decimal

Tags: floating-point, decimal, ada

This post is linked to this one [Ada 2005 access type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725528/access-type-and-procedures). The goal is to use **Ada decimal type to get similar results as to hand (and calculator) computations in which 6 decimal places have been used in each intermediate step.**

As can be seen from the table below, the **values obtained with the Ada code starts to differ from the hand calculation in the last digit when further iterations with the Euler method are taken**.

One of the issues with the Ada code was with the line in the main code **diff.adb**: *return 2 * Real(X*Y)*; It doesn't matter if I leave it as *return 2 * X * Y* as well.

The differential equation (O.D.E.) is being solved using the basic Euler method (which is an approximate method which is not that accurate).
The D.E. is dy/dx = 2*x*y. The initial condition is at y0(x=x0=1) = 1. The analytical solution is y = e^((x^2)-1). The objective is to obtain y(x=1.5).

We start with the point (x0,y0) = (1,1). We use a step size h = 0.1 i.e. x is increased with each iteration in the Euler method to 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,..etc. and the corresponding value of y (the variable whose solution is being sought) is determined from the Euler algorithm which is:

y(n) = y(n-1) + h * f(x(n-1), y(n-1))

Here y(n-1) when we start the algorithm is y(0) = 1. Also x(n-1) is our starting x(0) = 1. The function f is the derivative function dy/dx given above as dy/dx = 2*x*y.

Briefly, h * f(x(n-1), y(n-1)) is the "horizontal distance between two successive x values" multiplied by the gradient. The gradient formula is dy/dx = delta y /delta x which gives delta y or (the change in y) as

delta y = delta x * dy/dx.

In the Euler formula h is the delta x and dy/dx is the gradient. So h * f(x(n-1), y(n-1))  gives delta y which is the change in the value of y i.e. delta y. This change in y is then added to the previous value of y. The Euler method is basically a first order Taylor approximation with a small change in x. A gradient line is drawn to the curve and the next value of the solution variable y is on this tangent line at the successive value of x i.e. xnew = xold + h where h is the step.

The table next shows the solution values for the variable y by the Euler method when calculated by hand (and calculator), by my Ada code and finally in the last column the exact solution.

| x | y (hand) | Ada code | y (exact) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 1.200000 | 1.200000 | 1.233678 |
| 1.2 | 1.464000 | 1.464000 | 1.552707 |
| 1.3 | 1.815360 | 1.815360 | 1.993716 |
| 1.4 | 2.287354 | 2.287353 | 2.611696 |
| 1.5 | 2.927813 | 2.927811 | 3.490343 |

By hand and calculator for instance, y(x=1.1) i.e y(1) at x = x(1) is calculated as
y(x=1.1) = y(0) + h * f(x=1,y=1) = 1 + 0.1 * (2 * 1*  1) = 1.200000 to 6 d.p.

y(2) is calculated at x = x(2) as
y(x=1.2) = y(1) + h * f(x=1.1,y=1.200000) = 1.200000 + 0.1 * (2 * 1.1*  1.200000) = 1.464000 to 6 d.p.

y(3) is calculated at x = x(3) as
y(x=1.3) = y(2) + h * f(x=1.2,y=1.464000) = 1.464000 + 0.1 * (2 * 1.2*  1.464000) = 1.815360 to 6 d.p.

y(4) is calculated at x = x(4) as
y(x=1.4) = y(3) + h * f(x=1.3,y=1.815360) = 1.815360 + 0.1 * (2 * 1.3*  1.815360) = 2.287354 to 6 d.p.

y(5) is calculated at x = x(5) as
y(x=1.5) = y(4) + h * f(x=1.4,y=2.287354) = 2.287354 + 0.1 * (2 * 1.4*  2.287354) = 2.927813 to 6 d.p.

Now I want to modify the codes so that they work with a fixed number of decimal places which is 6 here after the decimal place.

The main code is **diff.adb**:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Euler;
procedure Diff is

  type Real is delta 0.000001 digits 9;
  type Vector is array(Integer range <>) of Real;
  type Ptr is access function (X: Real; Y: Real) return Real;
   
  package Real_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Decimal_IO(Num => Real); 
  use Real_IO; 

  procedure Solve is new Euler(Decimal_Type => Real, Vector_Type => Vector, Function_Ptr => Ptr);

  function Maths_Func(X: Real; Y: Real) return Real is
  begin
    return 2 * Real(X*Y);
  end Maths_Func;

  
  Answer: Vector(1..6);

begin
  Solve(F => Maths_Func'Access, Initial_Value => 1.0, Increment => 0.1, Result => Answer);
  for N in Answer'Range loop
    Put(1.0 + 0.1 * Real(N-1), Exp => 0);
    Put( Answer(N), Exp => 0);
    Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  end loop;
end Diff;
```

Then comes **euler.ads**:

```
generic
  type Decimal_Type is delta <> digits <>;
  type Vector_Type is array(Integer range <>) of Decimal_Type;
  type Function_Ptr is access function (X: Decimal_Type; Y: Decimal_Type) return Decimal_Type;
procedure Euler(
  F: in Function_Ptr; Initial_Value, Increment: in Decimal_Type; Result: out Vector_Type);
```

and the package body **euler.adb**

```
procedure Euler
  (F : in Function_Ptr; Initial_Value, Increment : in Decimal_Type; Result : out Vector_Type)
is
   Step : constant Decimal_Type := Increment;
   Current_X : Decimal_Type := 1.0;

begin
   Result (Result'First) := Initial_Value;
   for N in Result'First + 1 .. Result'Last loop
      Result (N) := Result (N - 1) + Step * F(Current_X, Result (N - 1));
      Current_X := Current_X + Step;
   end loop;
end Euler;
```

On compilation, I get the messages pointing to **diff.adb**:

**type cannot be determined from context**

**explicit conversion to result type required**

for the line **return 2.0 times X times Y**;

Perhaps the **2.0** is causing the trouble here. How to convert this Float number to Decimal?

I believe that further down in **diff.adb**, I will get the same issue with the line:

```
Solve(F => Maths_Func'Access, Initial_Value => 1.0, Increment => 0.1, Result => Answer);
```

for it contains Floating point numbers as well.

The compilation was done on Windows with the 32-bit GNAT community edition of year 2011. Why 2011? This is because I like the IDE better for that year rather than the pale ones which come in the recent years.

**The revised codes based on trashgod codes which work are given next:**

The main file **diff.adb**

```
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions; use Ada.Numerics;
with Ada.Text_IO;                               use Ada.Text_IO;
with Euler;

procedure Diff is

   type Real is digits 7;
   type Vector is array (Positive range <>) of Real;
   type Ptr is access function (X : Real; Y : Real) return Real;
   type Round_Ptr is access function (V : Real) return Real;

   procedure Solve is new Euler (Float_Type => Real, Vector => Vector, Function_Ptr => Ptr, Function_Round_Ptr => Round_Ptr);
   package Real_Functions is new Generic_Elementary_Functions (Real);
   use Real_Functions;
   package Real_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Real);
   use Real_IO;

   function DFDX (X, Y : Real) return Real is (2.0 * X * Y);
   function F (X : Real) return Real is (Exp (X**2.0 - 1.0));
   function Round (V : in Real) return Real is (Real'Rounding (1.0E6 * V) / 1.0E6);

   XI      : constant Real := 1.0;
   YI      : constant Real := 1.0;
   Step    : constant Real := 0.1;
   Result  : Vector (Positive'First .. 6); --11 if step = 0.05
   X_Value : Real;

begin
   Solve (DFDX'Access, Round'Access, XI, YI, Step, Result);
   Put_line("        x      calc     exact     delta");
   for N in Result'Range loop
      X_Value := 1.0 + Step * Real (N - 1);
      Put (X_Value, Exp => 0);
      Put (" ");
      Put (Result (N), Exp => 0);
      Put (" ");
      Put (F (X_Value), Exp => 0);
      Put (" ");
      Put (Result (N) - F (X_Value), Exp => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   end loop;
end Diff;
```

The file **euler.ads**

```
generic
   type Float_Type is digits <>;
   type Vector is array (Positive range <>) of Float_Type;
   type Function_Ptr is access function (X, Y : Float_Type) return Float_Type;
   type Function_Round_Ptr is access function (V : Float_Type) return Float_Type;
procedure Euler
  (DFDX : in Function_Ptr; Round : Function_Round_Ptr; XI, YI, Step : in Float_Type; Result : out Vector);
```

The file **euler.adb**

```
procedure Euler
  (DFDX : in Function_Ptr; Round : Function_Round_Ptr; XI, YI, Step : in Float_Type; Result : out Vector)
is
   H : constant Float_Type := Step;
   X : Float_Type          := XI;
begin
   Result (Result'First) := YI;
   for N in Result'First + 1 .. Result'Last loop
       Result (N) :=  Round(Result (N - 1)) + Round(H * DFDX (X, Result (N - 1)));
       X          := X + Step;
   end loop;
end Euler;
```

giving the output with **step h = 0.1 **

| x | calc (Ada) | exact | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 1.200000 | 1.233678 | 1.233678 |
| 1.2 | 1.464000 | 1.552707 | -0.033678 |
| 1.3 | 1.815360 | 1.993716 | -0.088707 |
| 1.4 | 2.287354 | 2.611696 | -0.178356 |
| 1.5 | 2.927813 | 3.490343 | -0.562530 |

The **calc (Ada)** results agree with **hand (and calculator)** computations.

Comment: Is it correct to infer that your goal is to asses limited precision calculations, not merely to display limited precision results?

Comment: @ trashgod Not really to assess. But numerical methods for ordinary differential equations such as the family of Euler methods and the family of Runge kutta methods are computed in all textbooks to a fixed decimal places when the calculations are shown step by step say by hand and a calcuator. I wanted to reproduce such step by step calculations in which intermediate values are kept to a fixed number of decimal places say 6. But I have tried with Mathcad and its rounding function round(number, no of d.p.) does the trick and I get similar results as by hand and calculator.

Comment: @trashgod I have now put as much information as I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `2.0` is a real numeric literal. It has type `universal_real` and may be implicitly converted to any real type, including your type `Real`. So this problem has nothing to do with floating <-> decimal conversions.

Canonically, fixed-point types are represented by an integer; the equivalent value is the stored integer multiplied by the delta for the type.* So for a value `X` there is an integer `X'` such that `X = X' * Real'delta`. Fixed point types have some issues with multiplication and division: an expression such as `X * Y` is equivalent to `(X' * Real'delta) * (Y' * Real'delta) = X' * Y' * Real'delta ** 2`, which has no obvious type. Thus all calls to '"*"' invoke the operation on type `universl_fixed` yielding `universl_fixed` and requiring either a context that defines the result type or an explicit conversion to the result type.

The multiplying operators are defined in [ARM 4.5.5](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-4-5-5.html). Note Para 19.a/2, "we require an explicit conversion to be inserted in expressions like A * B * C if A, B, and C are each of some fixed point type." So you have to explicitly convert the result of one of the multiplications to Real; the context will then define the result type of the other multiplication.

But this canonical definition also allows a loophole for multiplication by integer values: `I * X`, where `I` is some integer type, is equivalent to `(I * X') * Real'delta` which has type Real (provided `I * X'` is in range). These are defined in Para 14. So for this case, your return expression could be `2 * X * Y`, which should work. No explicit conversion should be required.

In the general case, you will require a conversion to the desired type: `Real (2.7 * X) * Y`.

To get the same results from your code that you do by hand, they need to do the same thing. By hand, you're calculating a value to a large number of significant digits, then rounding it to 6 places. For your code to do this, you'd need something like

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Diff is
   type Real is digits 9;
   type Vector is array (Positive range <>) of Real;
   
   package Real_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Num => Real); 

   function F (X : Real; Y : Real) return Real is
      (2.0 * X * Y);
      
   function Round (V : in Real) return Real is
      (Real'Rounding (1.0E6 * V) / 1.0E6);
     
   Step : constant := 0.1;
  
   Current_X : Real := 1.0;
   Answer    : Vector (1 .. 6);
begin -- Diff
  Answer (1) := 1.0;
  
   Solve : for N in 2 .. Answer'Last loop
      Answer (N) := Round (Answer (N - 1) + Step * F (Current_X, Answer (N - 1) ) );
      Current_X := Current_X + Step;
   end loop Solve;
   
   Print : for N in Answer'Range loop
      Real_IO.Put (Item => 1.0 + 0.1 * Real (N - 1), Aft => 1, Exp => 0);
      Real_IO.Put (Item => Answer (N), Aft => 8, Exp => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   end loop Print;
end Diff;
```

I've used `digits 9` to allow for the extra significant digits presumably present in your hand calculations before rounding. I've output with `Aft => 8` to show that the rounding works; you'd want to use `Aft => 6` to avoid the extra zeroes.

This outputs

```
 1.0 1.00000000
 1.1 1.20000000
 1.2 1.46400000
 1.3 1.81536000
 1.4 2.28735400
 1.5 2.92781300
```

The lesson here is that decimal fixed-point is not a drop-in substitute for floating-point with rounding.

*Technically by the *small* for the type, but for decimal types this is equal to the delta.

Comment: Using a conversion to the decimal type  return Real(2.0*X*Y) gives the same compiler error messages as given in the post. But using return Real(2*X*Y) instead gives suucessful compilation and run.  And there was no complaint for the line Solve(F => Maths_Func'Access, Initial_Value => 1.0, Increment => 0.1, Result => Answer) in which we have values like 1.0 and 0.1. Why here then we don't need Real(0.1) and Real(1.0) for decimal type conversion? My goal is to do all calculations with 6 d.p. accuracy.

Comment: I could have been clearer, and got my conversion wrong. I've edited the post to hopefully be clearer and correct. No conversion is needed in the instantiation because these are simple numeric literals, not expressions, and so are implicitly converted to the required type.

Comment: Irrespective of how I play with the Ada code, I cannot get the same solutions as when I compute them by hand and a calculator for small step size h. There are are slight differences in the last digits. However a program such as Mathcad does give the solutions as I get by hand and calculator. In Mathcad I use the function round(number,6) to get my 6 d.p. after the decimal point easily. Regarding Ada, I tried Decimal_Type(Float'Truncation(number)) but I am not that successful either.

Comment: Without seeing what you're doing in Ada and by hand, I cannot comment. But if your hand calculation is `A * B * C` then rounded to 6 places, you have to take extra steps in Ada to do the same thing.

Comment: I'm surprised that your values are so close. IIUC, your hand calculation is done using floating point with a large number of significant digits, then rounded to 6 places. This rounded value is then used for the next iteration. Your code converts all of your intermediate results to Real, that is to an integer multiple of 1.0E-6. To get the same results, your code needs to do the same thing you're doing by hand. I'll edit my answer to address some specifics.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show a simplified version using floating point and rounding. I would think you'd want at least `digits 9` to duplicate the extra significant digits used when doing this by hand, but if 7 digits works then that's good, too. I guess the compiler is calculating all the intermediate results using the FPU's full precision and only converting to your type when the value is stored. As trashgod's answer shows, explicit rounding is not needed with `digits 7`.

Comment: I have modified my post to include a working code based on using the access type and on trashgod's code. Of course your code is simpler. I decided to work with access type as I wanted to learn this feature based on Ben Ari's Ada book in 2005 in which the access type is used to solve a differential equation with the Euler method. So I continued with my codes with the access type. Both the new codes in the post and your code are giving good results. In euler.adb, I also have a round here in Round(H * DFDX (X, Result (N - 1))) just to ensure that no strange result can come from this part. Thanks.

Comment: I have also used the rounding feature on trashgod codes as you see in my edited post at the end.

Comment: As it is my first time with generics and the access type, grateful if you could take a look at my latest code down in the question to see if the style is OK. Thank you.

Comment: My version is simpler because it is less general. A general solution is more useful, but a simpler version is better for concentrating on the concepts being discussed. You then take the ideas from the simplified version and apply them to the more general solution, as you have done. There are several things I would do differently, but as a learning experience your version looks reasonable.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter Thank you. The post is now on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284114/using-adas-access-type-and-generics-to-solve-an-ode on how to make the codes better in terms of the Ada language. This was a suggestion from trashgod to put the codes there.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug to me. It lets you do `return X * Y * 2;`
and `return X * 2.0;`
but not any expression that contains 2 multiplication operators and a variable. Another strange thing is that normally you'd want to do `return Real (Incompatibly_Typed_Variable) * X * Y;`
to convert a non compatible type, but it seems that fails with an error too. It looks the expression `return 2.0 * Real (X * Y);`
will work as a workaround.

Comment: Note: I have only used GNAT studio on windows to compile this, if anyone has any other Ada compiler, it would be nice to share if this errors too in the same way or if it compiles correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that changing the type of `Real` will improve the correspondence. The variation below produces the expected result. Try adjusting `Step` or `digits` to see the effect. In addition,

- `Diff` displays the calculated, exact and delta values for reference; in particular `F(1.5)` is 2.927813, which differs from the actual value 3.490343 by 0.562530.
- It uses the the initial values `XI` and `F(XI)`, which need not be the initial conditions.
- It scales the `Result` array size based on `Step` over a given `Interval`.
- `Euler` now calculates the next result and then increments `X`.
- `Diff` has been updated to index `Result` using `Natural`. A zero-based array corresponds more closely to this related [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Example), and the iteration scheme in `Diff` now recapitulates that used in `Euler`.

```
        x      calc     exact     delta
 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.000000
 1.100000  1.200000  1.233678  0.033678
 1.200000  1.464000  1.552707  0.088707
 1.300000  1.815360  1.993716  0.178356
 1.400000  2.287354  2.611696  0.324343
 1.500000  2.927813  3.490343  0.562530
 1.600000  3.806156  4.758821  0.952665
 1.700000  5.024126  6.619369  1.595242
 1.800000  6.732329  9.393331  2.661002
 1.900000  9.155968 13.599051  4.443083
 2.000000 12.635236 20.085537  7.450301
```

Recover using `gnatchop`:

```
--
-- Euler method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method
-- https://stackoverflow.com/q/75749137/230513
--
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions; use Ada.Numerics;
with Ada.Text_IO;                               use Ada.Text_IO;
with Euler;
with System;

procedure Diff is

   type Real is digits System.Max_Digits;
   type Vector is array (Natural range <>) of Real;
   type Ptr is access function (X : Real; Y : Real) return Real;
   procedure Solve is new Euler (Real, Vector, Ptr);

   package Real_Functions is new Generic_Elementary_Functions (Real);
   use Real_Functions;
   package Real_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Real);
   use Real_IO;

   function DYDX (X, Y : Real) return Real is (2.0 * X * Y); -- ODE
   function F (X : Real) return Real is (Exp (X**2.0 - 1.0)); -- Exact

   XI       : constant Real := 1.0;
   YI       : constant Real := F (XI);
   Step     : constant Real := 0.1;
   Interval : constant Real := 1.0;
   Aft      : constant      := 6;
   X_Value  : Real          := XI;
   Result   : Vector (Natural'First .. Natural (Interval / Step));

begin
   Solve (DYDX'Access, XI, YI, Step, Result);
   Put_Line ("        x      calc     exact     delta");
   for N in Result'Range loop
      Put (X_Value, Aft => Aft, Exp => 0);
      Put (" ");
      Put (Result (N), Aft => Aft, Exp => 0);
      Put (" ");
      Put (F (X_Value), Aft => Aft, Exp => 0);
      Put (" ");
      Put (F (X_Value) - Result (N), Aft => Aft, Exp => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
      X_Value := X_Value + Step;
   end loop;
end Diff;
--
-- Euler method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method
-- https://stackoverflow.com/q/75749137/230513
--
procedure Euler
  (F : in Function_Ptr; XI, YI, Step : in Float_Type; Result : out Vector)
is
   H : constant Float_Type := Step;
   X : Float_Type          := XI;
begin
   Result (Result'First) := YI;
   for N in Result'First + 1 .. Result'Last loop
      Result (N) := Result (N - 1) + H * F (X, Result (N - 1));
      X          := X + Step;
   end loop;
end Euler;
--
-- Euler method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method
-- https://stackoverflow.com/q/75749137/230513
--
generic
   type Float_Type is digits <>;
   type Vector is array (Natural range <>) of Float_Type;
   type Function_Ptr is access function (X, Y : Float_Type) return Float_Type;
procedure Euler
  (F : in Function_Ptr; XI, YI, Step : in Float_Type; Result : out Vector);
```

Comment: Glad you get the expected result. Yes, I meant to use the symbol `DYDX` for the original function; although `F` is just the formal name, I'll look a new name for the analytic solution. Please edit the question to include revised code; try `gntatchop` for multiple files.

Comment: The changes have been made in the post. But gnatchop is used when there is only one file .ada and we would like to break it into its specifications and bodies.

Comment: I am now in a dilemma whose answer to accept. You played with my own codes and I made some changes including the rounding feature from Jeffrey to make the codes work. Jeffrey's new code now works fine and is simpler with no access type. Both answers are OK and I learned much!

Comment: I urge you to accept the answer that helped you the most; you can also  upvote answers you found useful.

Comment: As it is my first time with generics and the access type, grateful if you could take a look at my latest code down in the question to see if the style is OK. Thank you.

Comment: I use `cat` to create the `.ada` file and `gntatchop` to restore it. Also consider posting working code to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: cat I think is only available on unix systems. I am using Windows. I have just read a bit about how cat and gnatchop are used to distribute files.

Comment: I like `MinGW`; more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat).

Comment: I see no reference to MinGW at the link you gave but I downloaded mingw-get-setup.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/ but the instructions are not clear where to look for **cat**.

Comment: The post is now on codereview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284114/using-adas-access-type-and-generics-to-solve-an-ode