# Square root of Big_Real in Ada

Tags: ada

I am trying to calculate the square root of big numbers (around 16 digits) using the `Big_Reals` package. I have the following square root function which uses the Newton-Raphson method

```
pragma Ada_2022;
with Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers.Big_Reals;
use Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers.Big_Reals;

function Big_Sqrt(X: Big_Real) return Big_Real is
    package Converter is new Float_Conversions(Float);
    use Converter;
    Z: Big_Real := X;
    Big_Half: Big_Real := To_Big_Real(0.5);
begin
    for I in 1..32 loop
        Z := Big_Half * (Z+X/Z);
        Put_Line(Z'Image);
    end loop;
    return Z;
end Big_Sqrt;
```

The output with input 1813789079679324 is

```
906894539839662.500
453447269919832.249
226723634959918.124
113361817479963.062
56680908739989.531
28340454370010.765
14170227185037.382

raised STORAGE_ERROR : Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers.Big_Integers.Bignums.Normalize: big integer limit exceeded
```

I'm assuming this happens because although the whole part of the number is getting smaller there is too much space being used for the decimal part but I can't find a way to reduce the precision of the decimal part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77623223/230513), Ada support for [*big numbers*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-A-5-5.html) offers  arbitrary precision but not arbitrary size; some details on the limits are discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.ada/c/jQTrBS4MviU). Truncating intermediate, undesired results is a reasonable approach. In addition,

**Iteration**: Note that the [approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Heron%27s_method) converges. Instead of iterating for a fixed number of loops, consider exiting the loop when the difference falls below a specified threshold, `Epsilon` in the first example below. A related example is shown [here](https://github.com/trashgod/roots#roots-of-polynomials-with-complex-coefficients).

**Output Precision**: Note that the [`Big_Reals`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-A-5-7.html) function [`To_String`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-A-5-7.html#p15) provides output control for the number of digits after the decimal point. The first example below compares 64 digit results with known values. A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75794375/230513).

**Available Precision**: Also examine the suitability the precision available on the target platform. The implementation-defined value of `Max_Digits` may be found in the [`System`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-13-7.html) package; the second example below illustrates your result.

`Big_Sqrt`:

```
--https://stackoverflow.com/q/77623041/230513
pragma Ada_2022;
with Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers.Big_Reals;
use Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers.Big_Reals;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Big_Sqrt is

   N : constant Natural := 64;

   function Sqrt (X : Big_Real) return Big_Real is
      Epsilon  : constant Big_Real := 1.0 / 10.0**N;
      One_Half : constant Big_Real := 0.5;
      Z0       : Big_Real          := X;
      Z1       : Big_Real;
   begin
      loop
         Z1 := One_Half * (Z0 + X / Z0);
         exit when Z0 - Z1 < Epsilon;
         Z0 := Z1;
      end loop;
      return Z1;
   end Sqrt;

   procedure Compare_Square_Root (S1, S2 : String) is
      V1 : constant Big_Real := Sqrt (From_String (S1));
      V2 : constant Big_Real := From_String (S2);
   begin
      Put_Line (To_String (V1, 0, N));
      Put_Line (To_String (V2, 0, N));
   end Compare_Square_Root;

begin
   Compare_Square_Root
     ("2.0",
      "1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379");
   Compare_Square_Root
     ("5.0",
      "2.2360679774997896964091736687312762354406183596115257242708972454");
end Big_Sqrt;
```

Console:

```
$ ./obj/big_sqrt 
1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379
1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379
2.2360679774997896964091736687312762354406183596115257242708972454
2.2360679774997896964091736687312762354406183596115257242708972454
```

`Stock_Sqrt`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;
with System;

procedure Stock_Sqrt is

   type Real is digits System.Max_Digits;
   package Real_IO is new Float_IO (Real);
   package Functions is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions (Real);

begin
   Put_Line ("Max_Digits:" & System.Max_Digits'Image);
   Real_IO.Put (Functions.Sqrt (1_813_789_079_679_324.0), 0, 4, 0);
   New_Line;
end Stock_Sqrt;
```

Console:

```
$ ./obj/stock_sqrt
Max_Digits: 18
42588602.6970
```

Comment: That seems like a much cleaner way to do it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A fixed precision decimal part can be achieved by multiplying by 10 for each digit after the decimal point, converting it to a `Big_Integer`, converting it back to a `Big_Real` and then dividing by the original multiplier. The `Big_Sqrt` function becomes

```
function Big_Sqrt(X: Big_Real) return Big_Real is
    package Converter is new Float_Conversions(Float);
    use Converter;
    Z: Big_Real := X;
    Make_4dp: Big_Real := To_Big_Real(10000);
    Big_Half: Big_Real := To_Big_Real(0.5);
begin
    for I in 1..32 loop
        Z := Big_Half * (Z+X/Z) * Make_4dp;
        Z := To_Big_Real(Numerator(Z)/Denominator(Z))/Make_4dp;
    end loop;
    return Z;
end Big_Sqrt;
```

This will truncate to 4 decimal points by multiplying by 10^4 = 10000, converting to a `Big_Integer` by dividing the numerator by the denominator (both of which are `Big_Integer`, making the result `Big_Integer`), converting it back to a `Big_Real` and then dividing by 10000. I could not find a better way to convert a `Big_Real` to a `Big_Integer` but this seems to work.